# Bad request with GraphQL api in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to make query shipment with GraphQL query API in ASP.NET Core 6 but I get a "BadRequest".

I expected to get the query details that I provide in my API like:

```
id
code
customerDue
timeFrom
timeTo
latitude
longitude
collected
paidToCustomer
```

Here is my controller:

```
public IActionResult shipment()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> shipment(int shipmentId)
{
    try
    {
        var query = @"
            query {
                shipment(id: " + shipmentId + @") {
                    id
                    code
                    customerDue
                    timeFrom
                    timeTo
                    latitude
                    longitude
                    collected
                    paidToCustomer
                }
            }
        ";

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://accuratess.holol-aldiar.com.sa:8000/graphql");
        request.Content = new StringContent(query, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var shipmentResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Shipment>(result);

            return View(shipmentResponse);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to retrieve shipment details. Status code: " + response.StatusCode);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle the exception
        return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
    }

    return View("shipment");
}
```

And this is my model class:

```
public class Shipment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime CustomerDue { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeTo { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public bool Collected { get; set; }
    public decimal PaidToCustomer { get; set; }
}
```

And finally my view

```
@model apiGraphQl.Models.Shipment

<form method="post" asp-action="shipment">
    <label for="shipmentId">Enter Shipment ID:</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="Id" id="shipmentId" value="@Model" />

    <button type="submit">Get Shipment Details</button>
</form>
```

After I submitted some query in my form like 101010, I got "Bad Request".

Any help will be great. Thank you

Comment: What message do you get in “bad request” response? This message usually contains some important details that highlight errors in sending graphql request

Comment: @Eugene ok, how can i know the details ? when i submitted the form to get shipment details i got the bad request

Comment: Debug your code and look closer to “bad request” response. I believe this response contains body with error message. This message will answer to you what do you do wrong